# Почему не выводится пагинация для записей?

Tags: php, wordpress

На странице выводятся записи

```html
<div class="uk-grid uk-grid-collapse vtop">
    <?php 
        $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 

        $args = array( 
            'cat'=>$category_id,
            'posts_per_page'=>'24',
            'orderby' => 'date', 
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged'=>$page );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                get_template_part('template/loop','product');  
            endwhile;
        endif; 
    ?>   
</div>
 <div class="pagination-links"><?php pagination(); // пагинация, функция нах-ся в function.php ?></div>
</div>
```

В файле function.php темы

```html
function pagination() { // функция вывода пагинации
 global $wp_query; // текущая выборка должна быть глобальной
 $big = 999999999; // число для замены
 echo paginate_links(array( // вывод пагинации с опциями ниже
  'base' => str_replace($big,'%#%',esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))), // что заменяем в формате ниже
  'format' => '?paged=%#%', // формат, %#% будет заменено
  'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')), // текущая страница, 1, если $_GET['page'] не определено
  'type' => 'list', // ссылки в ul
  'prev_text'    => '&larr; Назад', // текст назад
     'next_text'    => 'Вперед &rarr;', // текст вперед
  'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages, // общие кол-во страниц в пагинации
  'show_all'     => false, // не показывать ссылки на все страницы, иначе end_size и mid_size будут проигнорированны
  'end_size'     => 15, //  сколько страниц показать в начале и конце списка (12 ... 4 ... 89)
  'mid_size'     => 15, // сколько страниц показать вокруг текущей страницы (... 123 5 678 ...).
  'add_args'     => false, // массив GET параметров для добавления в ссылку страницы
  'add_fragment' => '', // строка для добавления в конец ссылки на страницу
  'before_page_number' => '', // строка перед цифрой
  'after_page_number' => '' // строка после цифры
 ));
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ){
 $args['container'] = false;
 return $args;
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно не работает? В <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-collapse vtop"> не выводится ничего? или какая-то ошибка? так же смотри в шаблон template/loop в нем может быть проблема

Comment: Нет самой пагинации, в loop только шаблон с данными

Comment: нет `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Comment: Добавил, но результата нет :(

Comment: Для начала нужно использовать родную функцию `the_posts_pagination`